# How can I shade and finish shading a quote, and how can I use a thick font for a phrase?

Tags: support, markdown

I am not expert in computers. I write posts, comments and answers, but I can't shade the quotes with the yellow colour. How can I shade and finish shading of the quotes?

How can I write a phrase or a word with a thick font?

Comment: I have a terrible memory for these things and there's about 3 different versions of markdown in use. When in doubt, there's inline help that's super useful as a starting point for these things if you don't want to use the buttons

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about quotes, you use a `>` in front of it:

> This generally signifies a quote of some kind.

You also have `>!`, which does a hidden quote, or spoiler (move your mouse over to reveal text):

> This is hidden until you put your mouse over it. Use this for spoilers, or other things you want hidden by default.

In the future, if you ever wonder how to do something, you can always click the "Edit" and see the markup of how something is composed. Or, you can check out [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for formatting help.